# Microsoft identity platform client credentials flow auditing

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We are using the client credentials flow in Azure AD to authenticate our API's when the caller is some type of daemon process. Our security policies dictate that we need to audit when access attempts fail. For the most part we have been able to accommodate most of the security departments requirements except for when the get token request fails. This could be due to a number of reasons such as an invalid client id, secret, or certificate. The endpoint we are using to request a token is [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token).

I tried a few examples demonstrating passing invalid parameters to the access token request. I then checked the audit logs & sign-ins monitoring sections of our Azure AD tenant expecting to see some type of authorization denied message. To my surprise there was nothing.

I've tried searching client credentials flow auditing on Microsoft docs and on Google but I have not been able to find anything in regards to auditing failed access token requests.

Is there somewhere in the portal we can view when the access token request does not return a bearer token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Should anyone need this in the future Azure logs Success & Failure access token requests in the "Service principle sign-ins" section.
[Click here for screen cap of logging location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYZck.png)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Azure AD doesn't put access token requests in the logs. You could add the content of access token requests when calling the endpoint in your code.

[**Audit logs**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/concept-audit-logs): The audit logs activity report gives you access to the history of every task that's performed in your tenant. Examples of audit logs include changes made to any resources within Azure AD like adding or removing users, apps, groups, roles and policies.

[**Sign-in logs**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/concept-sign-ins): With the sign-in activity report, you can determine who performed the tasks that are reported in the audit logs.

Comment: Thank you for the response. We have logging around the endpoint. What we are looking for is a way to view the access token requests. From a billing perspective they want a way to determine if something is generating too many access tokens. From a security perspective it would allude if something is attempting some type of brute force attack against the get token request. With the logging we have we can view who is hitting our endpoints but if the attacker only hits the token request and never the endpoint we would never know something nefarious is going on.